# Create initial User on Parse Server programatically

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

We would like to know if its possible to create a User on Parse server programatically, without sign up. 
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server

We tried this in cloud code.

```
 var user = Parse.User();
 user.setUsername("admin", null); 
 user.setPassword("password", null);
 user.save();
```

It creates a User in the Parse database but when we try to login we get an 'unauthorised' error response.We have ParseServer configured so email verification is not required.

This is for an admin console, where we will ship an application where the customer can login with username -> admin password -> password
Then once they are in the app they can change their credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed.

```
let user = new Parse.User();
user.setUsername("admin", null);
user.setPassword("password", null);
user.save(attrs, { userMasterKey: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var user = new Parse.User();
 user.setUsername("admin", null); 
 user.setPassword("password", null);
 user.save();
```

> Class constructor ParseUser cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).